# Initial value for reactive value

Tags: shiny

I am trying to put together a reactive UI in Shiny which shows or hides a question depending on the answer to a previous one and a result depending on answers to both previous questions. I tried to implement it using the reactive UI elements but ran into a problem which I think can be described like this:

Since Shiny automagically distinguishes which reactive components are on screen and which are hidden, it only creates the values for the visible ones. Hence evaluating the condition for the result fails since the second question is not even created.

Here's a simplified example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = 'one', label = 'Show question two?', choices = c(TRUE, FALSE), selected = FALSE),
  uiOutput('two'),
  uiOutput('result')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$two <- renderUI(
    if (input$one) {
      radioButtons(inputId = 'two', label = 'Show question three?', choices = c(TRUE, FALSE), selected = FALSE)
    }
  )
  output$result <- renderUI(
    if (input$two) {
      p("You're done.")
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am not sure how to give `input$two` an initial value (of `FALSE`) so that the condition can be resolved. I imagine that using `reactiveValue()` could be a solution as this could initially be set to `FALSE` but then again, I don't know how to assign it the value of `input$two` once that exists.

Comment: do you want to assign a value to a variable before you create it? would working with a non-existence condition of the input$two variable solve your question?

Comment: Do you refer to `exists()`? I tried to use it but it seems that it doesn't work with reactive values?

Comment: really `exists()` does not work, but `is.null()` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `req` to check for the existence of variables inline like this. Basically, it adds an `is.null` check (like in @Winicius Sabino s answer) and cancels outputs if the criterium is not met.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = 'one', label = 'Show question two?', 
               choices = c(TRUE, FALSE), selected = FALSE),
  uiOutput('two'),
  uiOutput('result')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$two <- renderUI(
    if (input$one) {
      radioButtons(inputId = 'two', label = 'Show question three?', 
                   choices = c(TRUE, FALSE), selected = FALSE)
    }
  )
  output$result <- renderUI(
    if (req(input$two)) {
      p("You're done.")
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```